# Is $m*n=mn^2$ an operation on the set of integers? associative? commutative? identity?

Tags: abstract-algebra

If $m*n=mn^2$, then yes I believe that it is a defined operation on the set of integers because I believe it to be unique and all m*n will be in the set of integers.

An operation is defined as a mapping SxS-> S, where $a*b$ is an element of S.
For every a,b in S, a*b in S
(1) $a*b$ is unique
(2) $a*b$ is in S

I do not believe it to be associative
since $2*(3*4)=2*48=4608$ does not equal $(2*3)*4=18*4=288$

I do not believe it to be commutative since
  $2*3=18$ is not the same s $3*2=12$

I also do not believe it to have an identity but I am not sure how to prove it

Does this seem ok?

Comment: Without proper typography, it's very difficult to see what your question is.

Comment: $1$ is a right identity (but not a left identity, because we don't have $n=n^2$ for all $n$)

Answer (score 1):

We have $\ast:\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}$ with $\ast(m,n)=m\cdot n^2$.

For a binary operation (like addition, subtraction, multiplication,$\ast$, ...) we (more often the not) write $m\ast n$.

We want to see if $\ast$ is associative or commutativ.

So if $(a\ast b)\ast c=a\ast (b\ast c)$ or $a\ast b=b\ast a$.

Commutivity:

$a\ast b=b\ast a\Leftrightarrow ab^2=ba^2\Leftrightarrow ab^2-ba^2=0\Leftrightarrow ab(b-a)=0\Leftrightarrow a=0\vee b=0\vee a=b$

So no, in general $\ast$ is not commutativ.

Counterexample: Take $a=2, b=-1$ then $a\ast b=2\cdot (-1)^2=2$ but $b\ast a=(-1)\cdot 2^2=-4$.

Associativity:

$a\ast (b\ast c)=a\ast (bc^2)=a(bc^2)^2=ab^2c^4$ while

$(a\ast b)\ast c=(ab^2)\ast c=ab^2c^2$

Now $ab^2c^4=ab^2c^2\Leftrightarrow ab^2c^2(c^2-1)=0$

So $ab^2c^2=0$ or $c^2-1=0\Leftrightarrow c=1\vee c=-1$. Where $ab^2c^2=0\Leftrightarrow a=0\vee b=0\vee c=0$

Counterexample: $a=1, b=2, c=3$

$(1\ast 2)\ast 3=4\ast 3=36$

$1\ast (2\ast 3)=1\ast (18)=324$

So $\ast$ is neither associative nor commutativ.

> Is there an identity?

An identity $e\in\mathbb{Z}$ must satisfy $e\ast a=a$ and $a\ast e=a$.

So $e\ast a=a\ast e\Leftrightarrow ea^2=ae^2\Leftrightarrow ea(a-e)=0$

This equality holds for $e=0$ or $e=a$. But $e=0$ is no identity, since $0\ast a=0$ which is in general not equal to $a$. And $e=a$ can not be an identity too, since $a$ varies and $e$ has to be unique (so for every integer the same).